# ケプストラムからPSFを推定して、ブレ画像を復元したい

Tags: python

この投稿はterateilでも同様の内容で投稿しています。

#### 前提・実現したいこと

現在、ブレ画像のケプストラム(フーリエ変換->対数->逆フーリエ)からPSF(点広がり関数)を推定し、そのPSFを用いてwienerフィルタなどを用いてブレ画像の復元をしたいと考えております。

現在、ケプストラムを導くことはできたのですが、そこからPSFを推定するための方法が分からず詰まっています。ご教授していただけると助かります。
また、python3系での実装を考えています。また、ケプストラムは以下のコードで導きました。

#### 使用画像

ブレ画像
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

求めたケプストラム
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from scipy import signal
import cv2

rekka_img = "bure1.PNG"

imput_img = cv2.imread(rekka_img,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

kepusutoramu = np.fft.fft2(imput_img)
kepusutoramu = np.log(np.abs(kepusutoramu))
kepusutoramu = np.fft.ifft2(kepusutoramu).real
kepusutoramu = np.fft.ifftshift(kepusutoramu)

kepusutoramu_c = np.clip((kepusutoramu-np.min(kepusutoramu)), 0, np.min(kepusutoramu)*-2.0)
plt.imshow((kepusutoramu_c), cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('rekka Cepstrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/313854) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。質問文に追記させていただきます。